# NASM String cutting or manipulating

Tags: string, assembly, nasm, masm

I have an assignment where I am reader a User's Input from the buffer however it includes the enter button used to terminate their input. How would I either get rid of the enter button from the string OR add the enter button into my String while searching through my case table.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Sincerely,
Kayla

Comment: _"while searching through my case table"_ Why don't you just stop the string matching if you encounter a newline character?

Comment: Do a cmp with ascii code for newline?

Comment: if you are receiving user input into some kind of buffer, that means you can write into buffer. So you can modify the string before search in any way you wish, as long as the modified string does still fit into the buffer. Replacing newline with zero or space is definitely an valid option, you just have to find where the newline is (how long the user input was), if you don't have this info directly from the routine collecting user input. But if you are searching for some substring, then you can detect the newline as end of word... etc.. many options, depends what exactly you want to end with.